# Last elements in my layout not displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to the android developpement world (i just started yesterday).

I have a problem with a layout, here is the code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.simplecalculator.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculator" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_plus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="plusOperation"
            android:text="@string/plus" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_minus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:onClick="minusOperation"
            android:text="@string/minus" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_multiply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:onClick="multiplyOperation"
            android:text="@string/multiply" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_divide"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:onClick="divideOperation"
            android:text="@string/divide" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/second_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/equal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is the elements inside the LinearLayout LinearLayout02 (1 EditText and 2 TextView) are not displayed for some reason ? Can some one help me with this issue please ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried making them relative rather than linear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

This sub-layout has its height set to `fill_parent` so it expands to fill the entire screen. Set it to `wrap_content`. The same applies to

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

A few points:

use `match_parent` since `fill_parent` has been deprecated.

You are nesting way too many layouts. Please, consider using a `RelativeLayout` for performance improvements.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

in both of your `LinearLayout`s so the first isn't leaving room for the second. Change that in both to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Also note that `fill_parent` is deprecated and you should be using `match_parent` instead.